# Why do I get 2 different results when checking sha256sum of a file?

Tags: curl, wget, checksum

I'm trying to get the checksum of a downloaded file, so I can ensure it gets deployed correctly from an ansible playbook. I discovered that I get two different results depending on whether I download the file first, or just check it via a pipe with curl.

Download and check:

```
$ wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.15/drush.phar
$ sha256sum drush.phar 
6999d72e51577b1e20cfaec87152d9905b714f5812861692877b8424a4e2358a  drush.phar
```

Check piped from curl:

```
$ curl -s https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.15/drush.phar| sha256sum
c703007cf15cbabbeb510031ded52e7482f85dd3cce037bf9bcb7d7749acaa23  -
```

You'd think they would be the same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mystery solved.

The original URL has redirects, which I need to tell `curl` to follow with the `-L` switch:

```
$ curl -sL https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.15/drush.phar| sha256sum
6999d72e51577b1e20cfaec87152d9905b714f5812861692877b8424a4e2358a  -
```

Voila. Now the checksums match.